# VS 2008 debugging: How to filter and iterate collections in immediate debug window?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I guess question says it all. I know one cannot use lambdas in immediate window, but sometimes I need to either filter a collection or display property of the items in the collection for each entry. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. You would have to create a method that does your filtering, recompile, then use your method from the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but have you looked at creating your own [debugger visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)?  The only custom debugger visualizer I've used is the one from Scott Gu for evaluating LINQ to SQL expressions, but I haven't written on myself so I don't know the limitations.